# Error when mocking static method using mock static using Junit-5

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I am getting below error:

> The used MockMaker SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker does not support the
> creation of static mocks Mockito's inline mock maker supports static
> mocks based on the Instrumentation API. You can simply enable this
> mock mode, by placing the 'mockito-inline' artifact where you are
> currently using 'mockito-core'. Note that Mockito's inline mock maker
> is not supported on Android.
>
> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: The used MockMaker
> SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker does not support the creation of static
> mocks

When mocking static method using mock-static in my unit test.

I read online and I am even using below test dependencies

> JUnit5 = 5.x; JUnit-4-12-migration = 5.x; Mockito = 3.x;
> Mockito-inline = 3.x;

Below is my code (modified names of variables due to confidentiality)

I have a static class which contains static method (this class and library is maintained by separate team and I can't control them), so below is

```
EmailSendStaticClass.publishMail(email);
```

Now, I have to mock this method, so I used mock static

```
try (MockedStatic<EmailSendStaticClass> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(EmailSendStaticClass.class)){
            EmailSendStaticClass.publishMail(email);
            assertNotNull(email);
            utilities.verify(()->EmailSendStaticClass.publishMail(email));
        }
```

Please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: Are you importing both mockito and mockito-inline?

Comment: Yes, I imported both as I have mentioned in question as well.

Comment: Leave only `mockito-inline` - it is a replacement for `mockito-core` with a different MockMaker

Comment: issue got resolved, I didn't sync up my local code with remote internal set of dependencies, doing which fixed the issue.